# Run python code from terminal with a custom command

Tags: python, bash, shell

I couldn't find any question about this. Maybe because I'm not using the correct names.

### Given the following files

```
- my_proyect/
  - app/
    - __init__.py
    - cat.py
    - cow.py
  - venv/
    - ... (virtual environment)
```

### Contents

`__init__.py`

```py
from . import cat
from app import cow # Just to change the import form
```

`cat.py`

```py
print("meow")
```

`cow.py`

```py
print("muuu")
```

### Question

What should I do in order to run my `app` with just entering `app` in the terminal? (after activating my virtual environment)

The idea would be that this command is "stored" (don't know the correct name) inside my virtual environment, and not all my terminals.

I know I can execute it with:

```sh
$ python3 -m app
```

But I want to do this:

```sh
$ app
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This would be pretty similar as flask. Calling `flask run` is the same as `python3 -m flask run`

Comment: Have you tried creating an alias in .bashrc?

Comment: Do you mean `.bashrc` from the home folder (linux)? Because I want it to load from the virtual environment. I couldn't find a `.bashrc` in `venv/` folder.